# Where to find touchpad settings in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: touchpad, hp, 13.10, scrolling

I upgraded to 13.10 yesterday and when I opened some website I found that the two-finger scrolling is off and I am back to edge scrolling. When I tried to fix it through the System Settings I couldn't find the touch pad settings. All I found was the mouse settings. A screen shot is attached.

FYI, the touch pad is working fine. Also attached a screen shot from dconf Editor.

My laptop is HP Pavilion G4.

[image: mouse & touchpad]

[image: dconf editor]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just worked! I didn't even do a restart...

Edit: I tried to post this earlier but I couldn't cuz of some 8-hours rule.

Answer (score 3):

If you type `xinput list` you should see something like that:

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
↳ PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                   id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
↳  USB OPTICAL MOUSE                        id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
Virtual core keyboard                       id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
(...)
```

Can you see your touchpad on the list? If yes try

```
xinput set-prop [id device number from above] "Device Enabled" 1
```

Then check if touchpad appears on "Mouse & Touchpad" tab on "System Settings". For more specific input (like Two-Finger Scrolling etc)  check [this wiki here](http://www.mepis.org/docs/en/index.php?title=Configuring_the_touchpad_with_xinput).

Note that to me it did NOT work (even though from times to times it does appear on "Mouse & Touchpad" tab)!!  I am in the direr situation where my touchpad (Toshiba Satellite laptop with Ubuntu 13.10) does not respond at all and I have to use an external mouse all the time. It seems it is a bug that still Ubuntu team hasn't fixed.

Give it a try and let me know what happened - it's not going to harm your system after all.

Also, check this [SynapticsTouchpad](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad) and this [synaptiks.management – Touchpad management](http://synaptiks.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/management.html) webpages.